# Ultrafilters on naturals determine p-adic numbers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, filters

While preparing for a short lecture on ultrafilters for undergraduates, I realized some interesting things I have never read about.
Though I'm asking now a specific question, any reference about this idea is welcome.

Let $\beta(X)$ denote the set of ultrafilters on $X$.
By the principal filters we obtain an embedding $X\hookrightarrow \beta(X)$, so ultrafilters can be regarded as '*generalized elements*' joined to our set $X$, as this is often done in topology.

The main observation is, that *unary predicates* can be perfectly evaluated to ultrafilters themselves (without referring to any ultraproduct or such), as the interpretation of unary predicates are just the subsets of $X$.
For example, every nonprincipal ultrafilter $U$ on $\Bbb N$ satisfies $x>n$ for every fixed $n\in\Bbb N$, by which I simply mean $$\{x\in\Bbb N:x>n\}\ \in\  U\,.$$

Specifically, every ultrafilter $U\in\beta(\Bbb N)$ *has a last digit* in any number system $n$, in the sense that exactly one of the below sets will belong to $U$: $\ n\Bbb N,\ n\Bbb N+1,\ \dots,\ n\Bbb N+(n-1)$, since their disjoint union is the full set $\Bbb N$.
But this gives rise to a well defined function $\Phi:\beta(\Bbb N)\to\hat{\Bbb Z}=\prod_p\Bbb Z_p$ where $\Bbb Z_p$ denotes the set of $p$-adic integers.

**Question:** Is $\Phi$ surjective? In particular, does there exist an ultrafilter for every $p$-adic integer?

**Attempt.** Assume $a\in\Bbb Z_p$ is given. I'd like to define a filter and then extend it to ultrafilter.
$$\mathcal F:=\big\{A\subseteq\Bbb N \mid \forall n\,\exists x\in A: x\equiv a\!\!\!\pmod{p^n}\big\}$$
but the problem is that it's *not a filter*, though nonempty and increasing system, it's not closed under intersection, because if $a_n$ denotes the last $n$ digits of $a$ modulo $p$, then we can take $A=\{a_n\}\in\mathcal F$ and the disjoint $B=\{p^n+a_n\}\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: What about $$\mathcal F = \{ A \subseteq \Bbb N | \forall n, x \in \Bbb N , (x \equiv a \pmod{p^n} \Rightarrow x \in A)  \}$$Is this a filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set $\beta(\mathbb{N})$ has a natural topology that makes it the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, and your map $\Phi$ is just the unique continuous extension of the inclusion map $\mathbb{N}\to\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.  In particular, since $\Phi$ is continuous, its image is closed in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.  Since $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, this implies $\Phi$ is surjective.

Concretely, given $a\in\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ and nonzero $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $X_{a,n}$ be the set of integers that have the same mod $n$ residue as $a$.  For fixed $a$, these sets $X_{a,n}$ generate a proper filter (since $X_{a,n}\cap X_{a,m}=X_{a,\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}$) which can then be extended to an ultrafilter, and this ultrafilter maps to $a$ under $\Phi$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a=\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ is in $\Bbb Z_p$, i.e., is such that $a_m\equiv a_n\pmod{p^m}$ whenever $m\le n$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$A_n=\left\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:k\equiv a_n\pmod{p^n}\right\}\,;$$

if $m\le n$, then $A_n\subseteq A_m$, so there is a $\mathscr{U}\in\beta\Bbb N$ such that $A_n\in\mathscr{U}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and clearly $\big(\Phi(\mathscr{U})\big)(p)=a$. Thus, for each prime $p$ and each $p$-adic integer there is an ultrafilter that picks out that $p$-adic integer. (I don’t, however, know whether $\Phi$ is surjective.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way to look at your question which requires less topological background, and which I think is kind of elegant.

First, we note that to every ultrafilter $U$ on $\Bbb N$, there's an associated ultrapower of $\Bbb N$, which is simply $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}/U$. So, in some sense, your set of ultrafilters can also be thought of as the set of all possible nonstandard hypernatural extensions of the natural numbers; I will write these as $^*\Bbb N_U$.

Associated to any $^*\Bbb N_U$, there is a very interesting hypernatural number, which I'll call $\omega_U$, which is such that that the properties of $\omega_U$ determine the entirety of $^*\Bbb N_U$ and thus the original $U$. If we let $\omega[n] = n$ be the identity function from $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$, then we have

$$
\omega_U = \omega[n]_{/U} = \left[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...) \right]_{/U}
$$

where the notation means that we simply are looking at the element in $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}/U$ which is the equivalence class, mod the ultrafilter, that has the identity function sequence in it.

This means that if we have some unary predicate $\varphi(n)$, that we have the theorem:

$$
^*\varphi(\omega_U) \iff \{n: \varphi(\omega[n])\} \in U \iff \{n: \varphi(n)\} \in U
$$

which is a really powerful result: $U$ determines the properties of $\omega_U$, but also, the properties of $\omega_U$ determine $U$.

In particular, we can *build* a $U$ by starting with $\Bbb N^\Bbb N$ and looking at the sequence $\omega = (0, 1, 2, ...)$. Then, without even knowing what the equivalence class that contains it will look like, we know it'll be some hypernatural number $\omega_U$ associated to some as-to-be-determined $U$. So, we can ask: do we want this number be prime or composite? Even or odd? And so on, for every possible property (including very strange ones that are meaningless sets of natural numbers).

To be precise, for every predicate $\varphi$, we can ask: do we want the transferred $^*\varphi$ to hold for our $\omega_U$? We have to do this "coherently":

- For any predicate $\varphi$, we either have $^*\varphi(\omega_U)$ or $\lnot ^*\varphi(\omega_U)$
- If $\omega_U$ satisfies two properties $^*\varphi_1$ and $^*\varphi_2$, it satisfies the predicate that is their AND $(^*\varphi_1 \land {^*\varphi_2})$
- If $\omega_U$ satisfies two properties $^*\varphi_1$ and $^*\varphi_2$, and $\varphi_1 \implies \varphi_2$, then it also satisfies $^*\varphi_2$
- For the always-false predicate $\text{FALSE}$, we have $^*\text{FALSE}(\omega_U)$ is false

This is basically a restatement of the ultrafilter axioms in this perspective, so any such assignment of properties to $\omega_U$ also corresponds to a unique ultrafilter $U$.

From this perspective, your statement about each ultrafilter $U$ having a "last digit" has a very simple explanation: *every hypernatural* has a positional expansion in every number base, and the "last digit of $U$" is simply the last digit in the expansion of the associated $\omega_U$ in the corresponding $^*\Bbb N_U$.

Then we can prove something much stronger than your original question: given *any* $^*\Bbb N_U$, built from any $U$, we can take *any* hypernatural number $H_U$ in it that we like, and build a corresponding $V$ such that the corresponding $\omega_V$, in the corresponding $^*\Bbb N_V$, satisfies all of the same transferred predicates that $H_U$ did in $^*\Bbb N_U$. Why? Because the collection of all such predicates that $H_U$ satisfies is guaranteed to follow the "coherence" axioms above, so we can just directly assign them to $\omega_V$ using the above method and build $V$ that way. In particular, if $h[n]$ is any sequence in the equivalence class of $H_U$, we can look at the set of all satisfying predicates

$$
\Phi_{H_U} = \{^*\varphi: {^*\varphi(H_U)}\} = \{\varphi: \{n: \varphi(h[n])\} \in U \}
$$

noting that the image of $h[n]$ need not be all of $\Bbb N$. Then, to build $V$, we simply take all of the $\varphi \in \Phi_{H_U}$ and look at the derived subsets $\{n: \varphi(n) \}$, essentially the same as the above but replacing the $h[n]$ with $n$; these are the subsets in our ultrafilter $V$.

This lets us answer your original question directly by noting that all of the $\Bbb Z_p$ can be built as quotients of *any* $^*\Bbb N$, regardless of $U$: simply quotient by the union of all $(p^H \cdot \Bbb N)$ where $H$ is an *infinite* hypernatural number. In plain English: because of transfer, each hypernatural has an uncountably long base-p expansion going infinitely to the left, and our quotient map basically chops it off such that we get normal countable-length p-adic expansions instead. A similar method can be used for $\hat{\Bbb Z}$ using the mixed-radix "factoradic" positional expansion rather than the base-p expansion.

So, we choose an arbitrary $^*\Bbb N_U$, and some arbitrary p-adic integer $x$ that you would like to map to. Then there will be *some* arbitrary element $X_U$ which quotients to $x$. We then build a new $V$ by the above method: we assign all of the properties of $X_U$ to some new $\omega_V$, thereby determining $V$ in the process, and which will now have the property that $\omega_V$ quotients to $x$. Since we can do this for any $x$, this answers in the affirmative your original question if the map is surjective.